# How to grant all privileges to a user in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am connected as a root user in MySql.
Root user has GRANT and

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with grant option;
```

went through last time I did it without error code returned.

When I however change root to sqluser there is: "Error Code: 1410. You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
"

Earlier action:

```
grant grant option on *.* to 'sqluser'@'%'
```

and it didn't return error code. However as I ran query with localhost there is error code with number 1410.

I have MySql 8.0 installed.

How can I make grant all privileges go through?

Comment: In MySQL, the `'%'` wildcard does not match localhost.

Comment: "In MySQL, the '%' wildcard does not match localhost." Your sure? @BillKarwin the MySQL docs tells me otherwise  " For example, a host value of '%' matches ANY host name " source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69570 The `%` and `_` wildcards apply only to hostnames or IP addresses when using TCP connections, not `'localhost'` which uses the UNIX socket connection. It has always seemed weird to me, but that's the way it is implemented.

Comment: This means if you want a user & password for both TCP connections and localhost connections, you actually have to create two records in the `mysql.user` table, one with host=`%` (or some other specific host/ip address) and the second with host=`localhost`. It has always been this way in MySQL.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem when setting up a new mysql database, at the point of adding the first user.

I have found my problem was resolved by removing the @'localhost' from the GRANT.

This works:

mysql> `grant all privileges on *.* to 'laravel_user';`

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

This does not:

mysql> `grant all privileges on *.* to 'laravel_user'@'localhost';`

ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

```
mysql version:
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.12 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

I was following this guide to set up the database:
https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/developer-corner/mysql/managing-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line
```

Comment: you saved me many hours, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

**test this code.**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

Comment: There is Error Code with number 1064 (related to an error in SQL syntax) returned as for this one.